# Cannot use a csv file in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I was uploading a CSV file from my google drive but it showed me an error.

But when I upload it using the files section from the drive through colab, it shows:

data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/fire_archive.gsheet')

->**OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/fire_archive.gsheet'**

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add complete tracebacks and do not edit error messages.

Comment: Here's the tutorial https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=k9q0pp33dckN

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to open a Google Sheet file.
You can download the file as csv from Google interface.

And this message is not an error:

```
 Drive already mounted at /content/drive; to attempt to forcibly remount, 
   call drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True).
```

Is telling you that drive is already mounted.